# What LLDB command prints description of object with given address?

Tags: xcode, debugging, lldb

What LLDB command prints description of an object with given address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as `po 0x12345678`

Comment: Right.  To be pedantic, "po" evaluates the rest of its arguments as an expression that returns an object reference, then it figures out the dynamic type of reference and calls the appropriate description method for that type.  All ObjC objects are pointers, so it treats 0x12345678 as a very simple expression returning a pointer value and calls its description method.